# When to use a chi-squared test?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, survey, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

This is a very basic question however I do not have a statistical background and I am currently analysing some data for my dissertation.

I have constructed a survey about healthy lifestyles & obesity questions are mostly qualitative (How healthy is your lifestyle very/healthy/moderately - I have ranked the answers 1-5 to produce ordinal data. I have 330 responses.

I am looking to perform some inferential stats on my data to obtain some information on how (statistically) different answers are between different groups of participants, eg based on weight or occupation.

1. I am looking at performing a Mann Whitney U test to test for statistical significance between different groups within my participants (eg obese, overweight). However I am not entirely sure why this test is better to use than the t-test?
2. I have read around and the X squared/ Chi squared test seems also to be a good test of statistical significance to use on this sort of data. Is this correct?
3. Are there any other obvious tests (relatively simple) that I am missing out eg I have used ANOVA before but again not sure whether it is an appropriate test for my data.

Comment: You probably need the same thing as this questioner: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53407/which-statistical-test-to-use-for-likert-scale-questionaire/53409#53409.  You also need to be careful because it sounds like you are thinking of doing many many tests to identify which factors are significant on possible multiple response variables.  You come up against problems from the data mining field (which, intuitively amount to, that you are bound to find some associations by chance if you look at enough possibilities).

Comment: Your objective is not very clear to me. What I could understood is that: How **lifestyle** and **obesity** differ for different group (based on **age, type of job, gender** etc for example ) of individuals.  Please clarify to get an answer.